# jQuery v1.11 and v2.1 slideUp and slideDown not respecting css display property

Tags: jquery

I noticed that after upgrading from jQuery version 1.9 to version 1.11 that the behavior of methods like `slideUp`, `slideDown`, and `slideToggle` has changed when applied to non-block elements (i.e., `span`) which have a css `display` value specified.  In the previous versions, such as v1.9, the `display` value would get set (after its animation had completed) **to whatever we specifed in our CSS definition**.  In version 1.11 and 2.1, the `display` value is not respected in this way (at least not for non-block elements).

**Is this a new bug in jQuery 1.11 and 2.1?**  I saw that in older versions of jQuery, other people reported similar problems, such as [this](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-effects-like-slidedown-that-leave-display-set-to-inline) and [this](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2185).  Those problems seem to have been reported as fixed, and in our experience with jQuery 1.9, that seemed to be the case.  But it seems like its broken again in 1.11 and 2.1.  Here is a simple reproducible example:

HTML:

```
<span class="b">block</span> <!-- notice this is not a block-level element... -->
<a href="#" class="toggle">toggle it</a>
```

CSS:

```
.b {
    display:block; /* ... but I need it to display like a block-level element */
    background:red;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var isExpanded = true;

$(".toggle").bind("click", function(){
    if(isExpanded) {   
        $(".b").slideUp();
        isExpanded = false;
    }
    else {
        $(".b").slideDown();
        isExpanded = true;
    }    
});
```

See it working in this jsFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonkylefrank/pqrdS/120/), which uses jQuery 1.9.

This produces the expected result when toggled open:

[image: result 1]

Unfortunately, jQuery version 1.11 (or 2.1) is not respecting our `display` value, instead setting it to `inline-block`:

[image]

This can be seen in [this jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonkylefrank/pqrdS/121/), where the only thing changed is the jQuery version.

Did I miss a statement from jQuery telling us that this behavior would be different in this new version?  [These release notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2014/01/24/jquery-1-11-and-2-1-released/) didn't seem to say anything as such, indicating that with this upgrade...

> "Your code shouldn’t break, it should just run a little faster."

Note: I realize that changing the `span` in this trivial example to a `div` may solve this problem, but there are times when we need to use a `span` that is given block-level style (i.e., you can't nest a `div` inside of a `span`), and we have a large production application with many such cases.

Comment: It appears to be a bug, although I don't have the time to flush it out at the moment. And easy fix is to change your slidedown line to `$(".b").slideDown().css('display','block');`

Comment: @j08691 We can't use `$(".b").slideDown().css('display','block');` because we need the `display` value to be **whatever we specifed in our CSS definition**, not automatically hard-coded to `block` because there are cases where we would need it to be `inline-block`. Our biggest use of `slideDown()` and `slideUp()` is in Knockout binding handlers, so we need them to just respect whatever the CSS definition specifies (which is what jQuery versions previous to 1.11 did).  Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up submitting [this bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14824) to jQuery and they confirmed that it was a bug.  They claim to have [fixed it](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14824) on April 30, 2014, with a milestone release of 1.11.1/2.1.1 (I haven't been able to test their fix to confirm yet).

Answer (score 0):

After sliding `display` property became `auto`. Add in css

```
width: 100%;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm not sure which browser you're using that shows a `display` value of `auto` after the animation, but in Chrome and Firefox at least, the  `display` value becomes `inline-block`. Also, setting the `width:100%` makes the animation look a lot different than it did when the `display` property was respected (like in pre v1.11).